# IB API EClient Concurrent Connection Support

Tags: java, interactive-brokers

The IB API documentation states:

**TWS/Gateway client class** This client class contains all the available methods to communicate with IB. **Up to thirty-two clients can be connected to a single instance of the TWS/Gateway simultaneously.** However, after integrating the packages into my Spring Boot application (Rest API), when I launch the gateway, it prompts me for a single username and password. Can anyone provide an example of how this could be achieved? I would like to fund multiple accounts and migrate my Quantopian routines, currently written in Python, into Java.

http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/annotated.html#gsc.tab=0

[IB Gateway Single User Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WyAF.png)

Comment: If you are using 9.2 > API 32 client applications can connect to a single application. i.e., Once u logged into your local TWS or gateway application using credentials, your spring boot application can get 32 connections or use 32 different ports to perform the operations. And "I would like to fund multiple accounts and migrate my Quantopian routines" didn't get this part edit your question, please. If you want the demo account credentials those are edemo/demouser and fdemo/demouser.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your response, I think I may have misunderstood what was being stated about concurrent connections. My thinking was that each single instance had the capacity to connect to 32 different accounts. Hence, the confusion. Thank you for the clarification. As to the second part of my question, it was predicated on the same misunderstanding. I have composed several successful algorithms on Quantopian.com. However, they have discontinued live trading. So, my objective here was to migrate those algorithms and replicate the behavior in Spring Boot through the IB API.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage several accounts, this page may be a help:

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/am/am/manageaccount/addorlinkaccounts.htm